# Error when attaching to a new window

Tags: watir

I'm trying to figure out the best way to attach to a new browser. I've been successful using the following.

```
browser.attach(:title, "title")
```

I was reading over at the Watir development group that the preferred way to do it is like this:

```
browser.attach(:title=>"title")
```

This syntax seems to work for all other other elements, except for the attach method. The error method I get is `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)`.

My tests are running fine, I'm just curious if the attach method should support both ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed the same thing recently. I guess it is a bug. Would you create a ticket?

http://jira.openqa.org/browse/WTR

Comment: This has been entered as WTR-439.

Comment: Thanks, I just got e-mail notification for the ticket. Notification is also sent to [wtr-development](http://rubyforge.org/mailman/listinfo/wtr-development) list, I am sure somebody will take a look at it soon.

Answer (score -1):

```
popup = Watir::Browser.attach(:url,'whatever')
```

seemed to work for me. Or instead of a popup I also used ie2?